# Detect UIPageControl page change

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I want to Add a `UIPageController` inside `UICollectionViewCell`. I created a custom nib file with a `collectionViewCell` inside. Inside the cell I added a `UIPageControl`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
     
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
      
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    setupPageControl()
}

private func setupPageControl() {
    
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 7
    pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.orange
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
}
```

How can I detect the page change? Also the dots are in the middle of the view, is it possible to put them on the middle?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Swift 5

### 1) addTaget

You can add a target that detect value change on your setupPageControl functions:

```
private func setupPageControl() {

    pageControl.numberOfPages = 7
    pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.orange
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlHandle), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Create a selector to change the value that you wants:

```
@objc private func pageControlHandle(sender: UIPageControl){
    print(sender.currentPage)

}
```

Comment: .valueChanged does not provide exact dot click. It advances only one page. How to detect exact dot click?

Answer (score 8):

[image]
From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol)

> When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page,
>   the control sends the  valueChanged  event for handling by the
>   delegate. The delegate can then evaluate the  currentPage  property to
>   determine the page to display. The page control advances only one page
>   in either direction. The currently viewed page is indicated by a white
>   dot. Depending on the device, a certain number of dots are displayed
>   on the screen before they are clipped.

Also you can use

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

Comment: I will try you solution later thank you. But It's wrote that the change happens by taping the controller, and sctually in my solution it's not possible to swipe to the next view. Is this normal? Shall I use a uipageviewcontroller and then put a uiviewcontrole on it instead of putting the uiviewcontrol directly on the collectionviewcell?